# Writing json object to json file

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

In my code, i successfully use this structure:

```
$.getJSON('Json_users_templates/SO_example.json', function(data) {
});
```

to get JSON data from local .json file to object.

Now i need some code to write changed object to another local .json file..

i tried to use code like:

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        dataType : 'json',
        async: false,
        url: 'http://your.host/save_json.php',
        data: { data: JSON.stringify(eventsholded) },
        success: function () {alert("Thanks!"); },
        failure: function() {alert("Error!");}
    });
```

and for .php-reciever

```
<?php
$myFile = "general.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_GET["data"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh)
?>
```

but it doesnt work and firefox shows an error in .php file..

i just need to write json object like

```
var jsondata = {
    name : "bobby",
    age: "77"
};
```

to .json file.. can i do it without using php? and should i add anything to output.json to make it accept new data?

Comment: you can't easily write in all browsers to disk on the client machine.

Comment: For reading/writing locally you might want to look into HTML5 Filereader and Filewriter APIs

Comment: What's the error in the PHP file? The Javascript looks fine, the problem is in PHP.

Comment: Why do you keep undoing my formatting of your code? Please use the `{}` tool, not inline markup with backticks, for blocks of code.

Comment: @ vlzvl `In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem API spec should be considered dead. Other browsers have showed little interest in implementing it.`   http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: @kougiland, thanx for the link. Do you know the reason? im really surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Browser JavaScript cannot write files to your server.

Which means you will have to use AJAX and some server side language (PHP, ASP.net etc.) if you want to write to your own server.

Browsers do a sandboxing of Javascript on web-pages so that they also cannot write files to the users computer. What you could do is send the browser a runtime generated file as if the user had clicked on a link and then the user could manually save the file. The new HTML5 Filewrite API **may** work but it is very new and most browser don't yet support it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a data:URI, Here is basically how I do it:

1) get all the content into a string, you can use

```
content = JSON.stringify(YOUR_JSON)
```

2) Build the data URI:

```
uriContent = "data:application/json," + encodeURIComponent(content)
```

There will be length limitations depending on browser type etc. Encoding in Base64 (`atob` /`btoa`) instead using encodeURIComponent might make things more efficient.

3) open a new window and "redirect" it to this URI prompts for a download location:

```
newWindow = window.open(uriContent, 'JSON');
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>While the correct way is to use **[HTML5 FileWriter API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)** to write files locally,</strike>
i have a handy piece of code which is usable the same way `console.log` is used,
although it does save .json files, but it *will* ask you where to save it.
Give it a try.

```
// for JSON debugging (saving to files)
(function(console) {
   console.save = function(data, filename) {
      if (!data) {
         console.error('Console.save: No data');
         return;
      }
      if (!filename) {
         filename = "console.json";
      }
      if (typeof data === "object") {
         data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4);
      }
      var blob = new Blob([data], {type:"text/json"});
      var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      var a = document.createElement("a");

      a.download = filename;
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.dataset.downloadurl = ["text/json", a.download, a.href].join(":");
      e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
      a.dispatchEvent(e);
   }
})(console);
```

Then call it like:

```
var some_json = {foo:2};
console.save(some_json,"newfile.json");
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently, the HTML5 File system API is *considered **dead***.

**In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem API spec should be considered dead.**

[Link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)

Comment: it works fine, will try to edit it to re-write already existing file